# Add append object to form-group input field in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to append a `form-group` input field with some additional informations. The form is based on a form grid layout using the `form-group` tag. I know it is possible to add an `input-group-append` to an `input-group` in order to append something to the field. But I don´t know how to combine both, to have a appendency at a `form-group` field.

Here are the two components, the form with the grid structure and the appended input field.

**How is it possible, to add the appendency (@example.com) to the forms email input?**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this helps

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```